# Use local gradle distribution instead of wrapper for new projects

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

I want to use local gradle distribution instead of gradle wrapper. I use IntelliJ for android projects. For starting new gradle projects I get and option window asking for which distribution to use (wrapper or local) which I dont get for android projects.

My issue is - when i create new android project, it automatically uses wrapper and starts downloading gradle dists. I dont want that to happen. I want to use one single gradle dist for all my projects (android + non-android). I know I can set the project to use local gradle afterwards but that not I want to do. I want avoid wrapper all together. I just want an option for gradle dists before my android project is created.

Is there any IntelliJ setting for gradle for this?

I mostly work solo and I have been using gradle wrapper for all my projects and want to start using local distribution instead. One reason is that gradlew downloads and bloats my .gradle folder (on my limited SSD). I know with 5.4.1 it periodically clears cache and I can also delete .gradle folder safely but I dont want to manage it that way.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571070/change-default-option-of-intellij-idea-gradle-plugin