# Change default option of Intellij IDEA gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Everytime I check out and open a project in Intellij I need to change the gradle plugin setting "Use Gradle from" from the default "'gradle-wrapper.properties' file" to "'wrapper' task in Gradle build script"
[image: Gradle plugin setting "Use Gradle from"]

Is there a way in Intellij 2020 to make the shown option the default?

**Reason I am asking**: Generated gradle-wrapper files are not in our VCS, but the build.gradle is, and it has the wrapper task configured with the desired version. So when I check out a project, Intellij does not find gradle.properties (and neither can download gradle from web, as that is blocked). I then have to change the option "Use Gradle From" manually each time.

Another solution I tried is to automatically run a script when opening a module, which would run `gradle wrapper` with a fixed gradle version for the module, hence generating the missing wrapper files. But I find no possibility in Intellij to trigger that upon import..

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change this setting for all projects. Please vote for this request: [IDEA-215792](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215792).